# What does toString() do in typescript file?

Tags: angular, typescript, tostring

I am a bit confused about this line of code. What is the work of .toString file and what are the elements that it is comparing ?

```
 if (this.PrasnaTemp[k].SirsakID.toString() === 
 this.SelectedSirsak.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

It functions in TypeScript same as it does in JavaScript.

## JavaScript

`toString()` is a function on all objects in JavaScript . You can read the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

## Summarized version

It should return a `string` representation of the object in question. The implementation in the object can control how it wants to format the generated string.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the owner may have one of SirsakID or SelectedSirsak has number type (int/float).

They convert to same type string to sure that === work, because if `SirsakID = 1` and `SelectedSirsak= "1"`, the `"1" === 1` will return false (it compare both value and data type)